# Flash Youtube Embed Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, embed

Ive embedded a youtube video into a flash file with different frames for different pages, basically when i click off the page displaying my video, the youtube video is still on screen and the sound carrys on playing. I want the video only to be displayed on one frame, and the sound to stop when i switched frames. Here is my code:

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var player : Object;
var mute : Boolean = false;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);
pauseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVideo);
muteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteVideo);

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
     addChild(loader);
     loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady); 
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
     player = loader.content;
     player.setSize(520, 265);
     player.x = 230;
     player.y = 370;
     player.cueVideoByUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/G-P9fO4g2Jc", 0);
}

function playVideo(event:MouseEvent):void {
     player.playVideo();
}    

function pauseVideo(event:MouseEvent):void {
    player.pauseVideo();
}

function muteVideo(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(!mute){
        player.mute();
        mute = true;
        return;
    }
    else {
        player.unMute();
        mute = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addChild` method adds child to the hole movieClip rather than to the currentFrame, actually there isn't way to add child to the give frame.

Possible solutions are:

1. Create empty sprite in the frame where you need to insert the player and use this sprite as the holder. Don't forget to stop the video when you leave the frame (you can listen the `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` event of player for example and stop video in handler).
2. add `onEnterFrame` event listener and check the `currentFrame` property, when it's the target frame add video otherwise remove video.

Comment: Thanks for that, i managed to make the video play on only one page using a sprite sheet but im still unsure how to stop the sound!

Comment: To stop the sound you need to stop video playback. Add _REMOVED_FROM_STAGE_ event listener to the player: _player.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onPlayerRemoved)_ and call _player.pauseVideo();_ in the _onPlayerRemoved_